# The http connection freeze when using mobile netwotk

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to make http request on blackberry platform, My problem is: When I make connection via WiFi it works good, but when I use mobile network it doesn't work and the connection freeze

Here is my code

```
    public static String getHttpUTFResponse(String url) {
    url = addConnSuffex(url);
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    byte responseData[] = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory()
                .getConnection(url).getConnection();
        int len = (int) connection.getLength();
        System.out.println(len);
        if (len != -1) {
            responseData = new byte[len];
            DataInputStream dis;
            dis = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());
            dis.readFully(responseData);
            dis.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error");
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection = null;
        }

    }
    if (responseData != null) {
        try {
            return new String(responseData, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static String addConnSuffex(String url) {
    ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    ServiceRecord[] records = sb.findRecordsByCid("WPTCP");
    String uid = null;
    if (records == null) {
        return url;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        if (records[i].isValid() && !records[i].isDisabled()) {
            if (records[i].getUid() != null
                    && records[i].getUid().length() != 0) {
                if ((records[i].getUid().toLowerCase().indexOf("wifi") == -1)
                        && (records[i].getUid().toLowerCase()
                                .indexOf("mms") == -1)) {
                    uid = records[i].getUid();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
        return url;
    }
    if (uid != null) {
        // open a WAP 2 connection
        url = url + ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=" + uid;
        System.out.println("**************** on conn" + url);
    } else {

        url = url + ";deviceside=true;interface=wifi";
        // Consider another transport or alternative action.
    }
    System.out.println("**************** on conn" + url);
    return url;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For network connection TransportDetective.class is more use full you can resolve lot of problem related to network.

[TransportDetective y URLFactory para configurar la conexion a web](http://ecuadorblackberry.ec/?p=425)

[Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879)